# How make two buttons in the top of navigation bar in xamarin

Tags: css, xamarin

Excuse me but i need help in 2 parts:

1. I don't know how make the buttons above the navigation bar (red rectangular region) using xaml file.
2. I noticed that the parts (1,2,3) is similar and I want do this part for one time and then make reference or some thing like that to call it in my xaml file with and change the title while i call it. I mean make this part only one time rather than 3 times and call it every time I need.
   see the following Image to understand what I mean:

[image]

can anyone help me in this?

Comment: I believe you can easily make use NavigationBar TitleView to achieve the design you wanted in NavigationBar... <NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Label Text="Hello World" /> //Any View is supported here...Modify it as per your design
</NavigationPage.TitleView>

Comment: @Aya, Do you want to add ToolbarItem for ContentPage?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT NO i know how add toolbar but when i can't large toolbar to contain items in two rows despite i use stacklayout it always show only the content in the first row only this is my code:<NavigationPage.TitleView ><StackLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="Cancel"/>
                <Button Text="Save"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Add Problem" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
        </StackLayout>    
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

Comment: @HamidShaikh thank you this help but i have a problem cause as in image i should make 2 buttons in row and the label in the next row but always it show only the upper row with it's contents this is my code:<NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="Cancel"/>
                <Button Text="Save"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Add Problem" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
        </StackLayout>    
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

Comment: Change your Parent Control to be Grid instead of StackLayout...  Using Grid you can have multiple Rows.... But for some reason you want to stick to StackLayout then do some thing like this... <StackLayout> <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">//your ui code</StackLayout> <Label Text="Title"/></StackLayout>    I hope this helps